# error in reasoning: logical operators in raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, boolean

I'm  processing a formula in QGIS raster calculator and have an error in reasoning.

Having the layers `a` and `b` I want to create output layer `c` under the following conditions:

```
(1) if a = 1 or b = 1 --> c = 1
(2) if a = 5 or b = 5 --> c = 5, whereas condition (1) should overrule condition (2)
(3) if a + b = 0 --> c = 0
(4) else a + b / (number of layers which are != 0; !=1; !=5
```

Below is the formula with comments and hopefully readable.

It actually works, but there is a `NoData` Output for `a+b=0`.

- *a=1 OR b=1 --> c=1:*

  ```
  (
      ("a@1"=1) OR ("b@1"=1)
  )+
  ```
- *a=5, b not equal 1; OR b=5, a not equal 1 --> c=5:*

  ```
  (
      (
          (("a@1"=5) AND ("b@1"!=1)) OR 
          (("b@1"=5) AND ("a@1"!=1))
      )*5
  )+
  ```
- *a=0 and b=0, -->c=0:*

  ```
  (
      (("a@1"=0) AND ("b@1"=0)) *0
  )+
  ```
- *a and b not equal 1; 5 --> c= average of a and b, disregarding 0 values:*

  ```
  (
      (
          ("a@1"!=1)  AND 
          ("b@1"!=1)  AND 
          ("a@1"!=5)  AND 
          ("b@1"!=5)  AND
          (("a@1"!=0) AND ("b@1"!=0))
      )
   ) * 
      (("a@1"+"b@1")/
          (
              (("a@1">=2) AND ("a@1"<=4)) + 
              (("b@1">=2) AND ("b@1"<=4))
          )
      )
  )
  ```

What am I missing?

I have a similar question pending for SAGA Raster Calculator, but would prefer using QGIS Raster Calculator.

Comment: Order of precedence is sufficiently arcane, and varies with language and plarform, that you ought to use parenthesis and indentation and line continuation and comments to make complex expressions as readable as possible.

Comment: hopefully it is better readable now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RQGIS, the code is easiest to understand, check this:

```r
##a=raster
##b=raster
##c=output raster
library(raster)
c = stack(a)[[1]]
c[] = -9999 # Temporal NoData value
c[a == 1 | b ==1] = 1 # Rule 1
c[(a == 5 | b == 5) & c !=1] = 5 # Rule 2
c[a + b == 0] = 0 # Rule 3
r = (a + b)/((!a %in% c(0,1,5)) + (!b %in% c(0,1,5))) # Rule 4
c[c == -9999] = r[c == -9999]
c[c == -9999] = NA # Back to NoData
```

Applied to an example dataset:

[image]

[image]

Evaluations:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Note: rasters need to have the same extension and resolution**, if not. `extend()` or `projectRaster()` functions can be applied

Comment: this looks very straight forward! What do know need Raster reclass for?

Comment: *Raster reclass* is the custom name of this script, you can name it as you want

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code a little. Now it works, I think.

```
(
    ("a@1"=1) OR ("b@1"=1)
)+ 

(
    (
        (("a@1"=5) AND ("b@1"!=1)) OR (("b@1"=5) AND ("a@1"!=1))
    )*5
)+


(
    (
        ("a@1"=0) AND ("b@1"=0))
    *0
)+


(   
    (
        (("a@1">1) AND ("a@1"<5)) AND 
         ("b@1" = 0)
     )*"a@1"
) +


(
    (
        (("b@1">1) AND ("b@1"<5)) AND 
         ("a@1" = 0)
    )*"b@1"
)+


(
    (
        (
            (
                ("a@1">1) AND 
                ("a@1"<5)) AND 
                (
                    ("b@1">1) AND 
                    ("b@1"<5)
                )
            )*
        ("a@1"+"b@1")
    )/2
)
```